My rear dropout notch is 12 mm (roughly 1/2"), am I correct in thinking a 3000 watt rear hub motor axle won't fit?
The bike is a Seattle Micargi stretch

The rear dropout width is roughly 180mm and the rear axle dropout notch was widened to 12-13 mm to accept a thru axle rim with a 12 mm axle. With the notch being made bigger, is there any way to make a fat tire rear hub motor work with the smaller axle they come with? Or is my frame ruined for such an application? Thanks to all for any help or expertise on this matter.

You've got options still. There exist adaptors to convert between quick release and thru axle, such as the generic example shown below: I am not sure if they are readily available in the length you need (which admittedly is quite unusual), but worst comes to worst you could probably get one custom made.

Alternatively, it may be possible to convert your hub motor to use a thru axle instead of the skinnier quick release (usually by changing the end caps fitted to the actual bearing axle). Take a look at the documentation for it to determine if that's possible or not.

Based on the manufacturer's web site, your bike clearly has axle nuts on the front wheel.  I can't see if the rear has the same or a QR or a through axle, but it's a safe bet the rear axle is nutted too.
This means you have dropouts, which are incompatible with a through axle.
It would be best if your new motor had a boring threaded axle and standard axle nuts.
Aside - 3kW is an enormous amount of power for a bicycle, and you will likely strip out the dropouts.  Look for a "Torque Arm" option for your motor, which will transfer torque into the frame better.
Also be aware this may classify your bike as an electric motorcycle legally, so consider the legal implications.
